# How do I get rid of buzzing sound while watching Youtube?

Tags: sound, mac, gnash

So, I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.1 on my iMac G5 and I think I have Gnash installed as a Flash player. The videos on Youtube load fine even though Mozilla tells me from time to time that I need a Flash plugin, I get video image just fine but as for the sound it's all just a scratching buzzing static. Sound works well like testing and listening to music.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just realized that the gnash plugin for Mozilla wasn't even installed and Mozilla was trying to play the Youtube videos using html5 and that's what was causing the buzzing. I ended up using Epiphany as both flash apps for Ubuntu worked very slow in Mozilla, I tried the latest version of Gnash and Lightspark. Imagine that, Mozilla not being able to play html5 from Youtube. And it was version 15.1 So it wasn't a sound drive issue after all as I feared...